# Facebook Ar Studio - adding hyperlink to website

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality

I am using Facebook Ar Studio and would like to create a link in the scene to an outside website when an object is tapped on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible - currently Facebook restricts this sort of behavior.

Comment: Dang, Thanks so much!